# System.Media.Soundplayer not a namespace? (mac)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to play sounds in c#, and none of the System.Media namespaces are working, instead giving the error:
`Error CS1069: The type name 'SoundPlayer' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Media'`
I'm am doing `using System.Media;` but it still gives the error.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Is it .Net Framework? Is it .Net Core ? Are you willing to play sound in WPF, Win Forms, Web, Mobile? When you asking a question, you should include details about the platform that you are trying to use.

Comment: I'm using the .NET Core, and just trying to play sounds with a .wav file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoundPlayer class provides a simple interface for loading and playing a .wav file. The SoundPlayer class supports loading a .wav file from a file path, a URL, a Stream that contains a .wav file, or an embedded resource that contains a .wav file.

It is for .Net Framework and not for .Net Core. Essentially, all of the sound-playing functionality that was available in .NET Framework was Windows-specific; therefore none of it made it into .NET Core.

For more information you can check [SoundPlayer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#examples) in Microsoft .Net Framework documentation.

Comment: This is wrong: it is available in the .NET Platform Extensions, which you need to install separately of .NET, since .NET Core 3.0.